# MongoDB on Azure DocumentDB create unique index

Tags: azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

When I'm trying to create unique Index on  Azure DocumentDB (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-protocol-mongodb/) I get following error:

[image]

Is there some way to get around this problem without using client code logic?

Comment: Not every MongoDB feature is implemented in the MongoDB Compatibility layer of DocumentDB. Looks like this is one of them. You'd need to implement this on your own. And while this can be done in several ways, there's [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31521930/272109) to a question regarding unique DocumentDB indexes in general, showing how this may be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Azure Cosmos DB not support MongoDB/Mongoose unique index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404613/does-azure-cosmos-db-not-support-mongodb-mongoose-unique-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure MongoDB has implemented a unique keys feature so using a workaround is not longer needed in many cases. You can find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys). But you define unique keys only when you create an Azure Cosmos container and a unique key is scoped to a logical partition. Some other limitations can be found in the documentation.