# Does Azure Cosmos DB not support MongoDB/Mongoose unique index?

Tags: mongodb, azure, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb

Using a unique constraint in Mongoose like:

```
email: { type:String, unique:true }
```

doesn't seem to work.  I can save several users with the same email.

Is there something I need to do to create a unique index?

Comment: You need to remove the duplicate entries from the collection **first**. The index would fail on creation because duplicates exist and therefore not create. Also another common cause is writing unit tests that drop the database, where the "default" background mode index creation does not complete before tests are issued.

Comment: @NeilLunn This was a new collection - I didn't have duplicates.  Further, I let it sit for a while before I submitted a second record with the same information.  I am familiar with the behavior of regular Mongo DB.  I am asking specifically about Azure Cosmos DB.

Comment: Mongoose has nothing to do with whether Cosmos DB's MongoDB api supports unique indexes. @NeilLunn's tag edits were correct, as this question is directly about Cosmos DB / DocumentDB (the tags are synonyms).

Comment: A lot of things are not supported, including aggregates, groupBy, etc. The best option is to use official MongoDb Cloud (Atlas) on amazon (it's cheaper than google cloud and azure).

Comment: Cosmos DB formerly known as Document DB does not support unique indexes. Triggers will not work since Mongo DB and its drivers do not support such feature; you have to specify what trigger to use as an option in your client code. As @DavidMakogon mentioned, checking for uniqueness needs to happen in the application unfortunately.

Comment: Now that unique indexes are supported (as of nov 2017), this question is obsolete. Probably safe to delete it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unique indexes are not supported today, in the MongoDB API for Cosmos DB. You cannot specify `unique:true` when creating an index.

You'd need to implement this in your app tier.

**EDIT** - As pointed out, this was officially released as of November 2017, with the MongoDB API.

Comment: to clarify, unique indexes ARE now supported, as of Nov '17. i also had problems creating a unique index on an existing collection. deleting all rows didn't fix. i had to re-create the collection and then add the unique index for it to work.

Comment: @LukeW - Look at my answer, which includes an edit from a year ago stating this.

Answer (score 1):

This might because your collection already has duplicated values for the field you specified. You need to delete duplicates or create a new database to enable unique index.

Comment: Correct - just updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: No need to create new database. You need to create new collection because createIndex with unique constraint only works on empty collection in Cosmos DB. If you're importing existing collection with mongorestore/mongoimport, just do it with --noIndexRestore flag after creating unique indexes on empty collection in Cosmos DB.

Comment: @alekseys Can I just paste your comments in my answer? And is there a way to check if unique index is enabled for a data collection?

Answer (score 0):

In the version 4.2, the unique indexes are supported theoretically speaking, but note that there must be **no data** in the collection as CosmosDB [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/indexing) says:

> Unique indexes need to be created while the collection is empty.

From my experience even when there is no data, you might need to **create the whole collection** from scratch with the unique index, otherwise you get an error.

As mentioned, there are also [constraints](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/) on **duplicates** & **hashed values** from the Mongo itself

> MongoDB cannot create a unique index on the specified index field(s) if the collection already contains data that would violate the unique constraint for the index.
> You may not specify a unique constraint on a hashed index.